# Can't resolve 'WindowedApplication'

Tags: apache-flex, air, fdt

This is my sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" paddingBottom="0" 
    paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0"/>
```

I am getting below error:

Can't resolve 'WindowedApplication'. Found at line 2 column 4.

I am using FDT 5 with flex_sdk_4.6 set up.

Can any one please help.

Comment: I'd guess you didn't include the AIR libraries.

Comment: Are you using FDT? Which project type are you using?

Comment: @Alan Klement I am using AIR>Desktop.@RIAstar How to add AIR lib.I have set up flex sdk already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the Flex Framework on your classpath.

You need a Project Type that includes the Flex Framework. You probably forgot to check the button 'Use Flex Framework' (pic below).

[image]

### To change project type:

**Right click your project and go to Flash Project>Set Project Type:**
[image]

**Choose Air Flex:**
[image]

### To choose Flex at project creation:

[image]